# How do you query a many-to-many relationship using Entity Framework Core 2.1?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1

I am trying to select data from a many-to-many relationship using EF Core (Code First) and am getting the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: must be reducible node

I don't think I am doing anything particularly strange, and I can happily run the query in question using LinqToSQL in LinqPad. Hopefully someone can point out where I am going wrong?

I have created a minimal (and contrived) reproduction in a console application, which can be found [here](https://github.com/benm-eras/ReducibleNodeDemo/tree/master/ReducibleNodeDemo). Basically I have modelled the many to many relationship using a joining table as [follows](https://github.com/benm-eras/ReducibleNodeDemo/blob/14085887d3e713302f6077926e9f3cdd49176aa2/ReducibleNodeDemo/DataContext.cs#L10):

```
public class Foo
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<FooBar> FooBars { get; set; } = new List<FooBar>();
}

public class Bar
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public ICollection<FooBar> FooBars { get; set; } = new List<FooBar>();
}

public class FooBar
{
    [Required]
    public int FooId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(FooId))]
    public Foo Foo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int BarId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(BarId))]
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to create a lookup of `Value` from the `Bar` object with the `Id` from `Foo` as the key using the following [query](https://github.com/benm-eras/ReducibleNodeDemo/blob/master/ReducibleNodeDemo/App.cs#L28):

```
ILookup<int, string> data = 
    this.context.Foos
        .SelectMany(f => f.FooBars.Select(fb => new { f.Id, fb.Bar.Value }))
        .ToLookup(fb => fb.Id, fb => fb.Value);
```

Before the error I get the following warning in the console:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[20500]
>         The LINQ expression 'from <>f__AnonymousType0`2 <generated>_0 in {from FooBar fb in value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[ReducibleNodeDemo.FooBar]) join Bar fb.Bar in value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[ReducibleNodeDemo.Bar]) on Property([fb], "BarId") equals Property([fb.Bar], "Id") where  ?= (Property([f], "Id") == Property([fb], "FooId")) =? select new <>f__AnonymousType0`2(Id = [f].Id, Value = [fb.Bar].Value)}' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

I am relatively new to EF Core, but have been working with EF6 for years and have never had a problem with simple queries like this!

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. IN the version of EF Core you are using, the above query can't be translated to SQL (or whatever db provider you are using). So the query will happen without it and the party that cant be translated will be filtered within your application in-memory. It may be a sign that you receive huge amount of data with that query because some parts of it have to be done in-memory inside your application

Comment: I don't think it's clear at all or I wouldn't be asking. Also it doesn't actually run so it obviously can't do it in memory either. It definitely isn't returning tons of data as the query never even hits the database. It is a very simple query, which other libraries can translate to SQL, hell even I can translate that to SQL. My question is how should I write a query to get the data I am after?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently you are hitting current EF Core implementation bug, so consider reporting it to their issue tracker.

It seems to be caused by the `Select` inside `SelectMany` and the usage of the outer parameter `f` inside the inner lambda. The workaround is to use the `SelectMany` overload with element selector:

```
.SelectMany(f => f.FooBars, (f, fb) => new { f.Id, fb.Bar.Value })
```

which I believe is used by the C# compiler when you use the equivalent LINQ query syntax

```
(from f in this.context.Foos
 from fb in f.FooBars
 select new { f.Id, fb.Bar.Value })
```

Another workaround/solution in this particular case is to start the query directly from `FooBar` (one of the advantages of the many-to-many with explicit join entity)

```
this.context.Set<FooBar>()
    .Select(fb => new { fb.Foo.Id, fb.Bar.Value });
```

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev! Perfect answer, immediately got me going again with the work around! I have posted a few other issues on thier repo in the last few months so will add this too. In this case I just thought I was doing something daft.

Comment: There was already an [open issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13680) to which I did add a comment with a link to your answer, but it's now not appearing! Will try again later